# Is it possible to mark tests as taking long time in googletest runs

Tags: c++, googletest

Most of my tests finish quickly, the time taken is unnoticeable. But a few of them take a few seconds. I would like to print a hint to the user:

```
TEST(something, thing) {
   std::cout << "This might take a few seconds\n";

   ASSERT_EQ(expected_result, long_computation());
}
```

This doesn't blend in well with what is printed. Is there a feature for this in googletest? I couldn't find anything related. Any way to make goggliest understand it, print a hint to the user, and even report error in case the test runs too long? Or any plugin that does this? Thx

```
TEST(something, thing, max_time: 3 seconds) {
  ASSERT_EQ(expected_result, long_computation());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anything like this exists but I believe you can tailor some of the features you want at least partially.
You can measure the time of execution of your test yourself and add statements like ASSERT_GT(time_limit, measured_time).
Consider using https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#logging-additional-information for writing the timings or "long"/"fast" attributes.
Consider using https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests for running only fast, or only long tests, f.e. run only fast tests (provided you named all long tests like *Long): ./foo_test --gtest_filter=-*Long